# Which lines are necessary to use espeak in our C/C++ program?

Tags: c, embedded, system, espeak

I found this code on the internet:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <espeak/speak_lib.h>


espeak_POSITION_TYPE position_type;
espeak_AUDIO_OUTPUT output;
char *path=NULL;
int Buflength = 1000, Options=0;
void* user_data;
t_espeak_callback *SynthCallback;
espeak_PARAMETER Parm;



char Voice[] = {"English"};


char text[30] = {"this is a english test"};
unsigned int Size,position=0, end_position=0, flags=espeakCHARS_AUTO, *unique_identifier;




int main(int argc, char* argv[] ) 
{
    output = AUDIO_OUTPUT_PLAYBACK;
    int I, Run = 1, L;    
    espeak_Initialize(output, Buflength, path, Options ); 
    espeak_SetVoiceByName(Voice);
    const char *langNativeString = "en"; //Default to US English
    espeak_VOICE voice;
        memset(&voice, 0, sizeof(espeak_VOICE)); // Zero out the voice first
        voice.languages = langNativeString;
        voice.name = "US";
        voice.variant = 2;
        voice.gender = 1;
        espeak_SetVoiceByProperties(&voice);
    Size = strlen(text)+1;    

    espeak_Synth( text, Size, position, position_type, end_position, flags,
    unique_identifier, user_data );
    espeak_Synchronize( );

    return 0;
}
```

I only want the `espeak` reads my strings in my program, and the above code can do it, but I want to know, are all of this code necessary for that purpose? (I mean is it possible to simplifying it?)

***Also I like to know are there a way to using `espeak` as a system function? I mean `system("espeak "something" ");` ?

Comment: Seems like a pretty straight-forward example? You have to read the manual about what those functions do. Also, there is no header file called malloc.h in the C language.

Comment: How much simpler could it get?  Looks pretty minimal to me.  You seem to entirely misunderstand what `system()` does.  If you can run it from the command shell, you can pass it as a `system()` argument - simple as that.  Your example will have to be modified to process the string passed in `argv[1]` rather than  `text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of eSpeak itself seems pretty minimal - you need to read the documentation for that.  There are some minor C coding simplifications possible, but perhaps hardly worth the effort:

The `memset()` is unnecessary.  The structure can be initialised to zero thus:

```
espeak_VOICE voice = {0} ;
```

If you declare `text` thus:

```
char text[] = "this is a English test";
```

Then you can avoid using `strlen()` and replace `Size` with `sizeof(text)`.

The variables `I`, `Run` and `L` are unused and can be removed.

To be able to pass the text as a string on the command line, and thus be able to issue `system( "espeak \"Say Something\"") ;` for example, you simply need to pass `argv[1]` to `espeak_Synth()` instead of `text` (but you will need to reinstate the `strlen()` call to get the size.